# How to create an AS/400 command with mutually exclusive parameters?

Tags: command, ibm-midrange

I need to create an AS/400 command. Based on the requirement, it has two parameter, say A and B, which cannot be filled in the same time. Both will be displayed when F4 is pressed to prompt, but only one can be filled at a time. If both are filled an error message should appear saying this is invalid. Can someone tell me how to create a command like this? What do I need to specify in the CMD source to achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [DEP](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/dep.htm) command definition statement to control the parameters.

```
CMD PROMPT('TEST')
PARM KWD(A) TYPE(*CHAR) PROMPT('A')
PARM KWD(B) TYPE(*CHAR) PROMPT('B')
DEP CTL(*ALWAYS) PARM(A B) NBRTRUE(*EQ 1)
```

Comment: Does the source above mean that one of A and B must be filled, but not both? This is what I need. The can't be filled in the same time but they can't be left blank together either.

Comment: @God_of_Thunder: It means 1 of the 2 parameters must have a value and the other must be empty.

Comment: @God_of_Thunder If you want display a message if both are specified, then on the `DEP` statement specify `MSGID(yourmsgid)`.

Answer (score 0):

The CMD source only has rudimentary ability to perform validity checking.  Typically, end user business rules are enforced by a validity checking program.  See CRTCMD VLDCKR().  The VCP is very similar to the CPP, except if the command fails validity checking, your VCP sends a *DIAG message to  the caller with the details of the reason, and a CPF0002 *ESCAPE message to the caller to tell it the command did not run.

Comment: In this case, a VCP is an overly cumbersome way to accomplish what is easily done with the `DEP` statement shown above.

Comment: Actually it's not a great amount of more code than the DEP statement, except the DCLs for the two parms muck it up more. It's just an IF statement and a couple SNDPGMMSGs. It's certainly more widely understood and accepted than the coding of *CMD objects themselves and the use of DEP statements. (Though I'd use DEP.)